# how to bind part of url to iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Environment:

asp.net core app

IIS

I want to map these two urls to different iis website with different application pools.

These two websites have the same domain e.g example.com but the only different part is after slash i want another websites handles file upload because of the time needed the connection to be open and so on

```
 - http://example.com

 - http://example.com/upload
```

so that i can do something like this in web.config in just the second url

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

or as my app is an asp.net core app be able to increase request time out

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\abc.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" requestTimeout="00:10:00" />
```

is the above solution is logical?

how can i achieve having these two bindings?

are there any other solutions for handling such scenario when an upload for security concerns and other reasons need to be separated from other part of the web app?

Comment: Just to clarify:  Do you want them to be processed on different servers/machines, or it is okay on the same server, but different app pools?

Comment: it is okay to be on the same machine but different website and app pool under iis

Answer (score 1):

They can't be different websites (as listed in IIS Manager) but they can be different app pools.

In IIS Manager, right-click on the subfolder ("upload") and click "Convert to Application". Then you can assign it to whichever app pool you like.

If it is not a subfolder of the site already, then you can right-click the root of the website and click 'Add Application'. Then select the name ("upload"), the app pool, and the physical path where the files are.

Comment: isnt it possible to write rewrite rules so that urls be proxied to another website?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I did think of that after. But it's much more complicated to setup, and it isn't necessary in this case (assuming both applications are ASP.NET).